# Как правильно организовать архитектуру таблиц фильтров

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

Всем привет, нужно реализовать такой функционал фильтров:
Фильтры создаются в админке со значениями - Название фильтра и множество значений, при добавлении товара пользователь выбирает подходящее значение из списка и это значение привязывается к товару.
Интересует как правильно организовать таблицы, я вижу это так:

1. Таблица filter

```
id|name |visible|
 1|ткань|true   |
 2|цвет |true   |
```

2. Таблица filter_atributes

```
id|filter_id|product_id|value |
 1|        1|        22|шелк  |
 2|        1|        23|хлопок|
 3|        2|        22|черный|
```

Всего 2 таблицы, у таблицы filter_atributes связь с таблицей products в которой товары, для того что бы выводить фильтры в категории. ПОдскажите насколько правильный такой подход или есть варианты более оптимальные? Сам проект на Laravel

Comment: Смотря как у тебя устроены сами товары и их модификации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от устройства логики связи между `фильтр`-`атрибут фильтра`-`товар`. Если логика такая, что фильтр `цвет` имеет много значений (красный, синий и т.д.), а одно значение фильтра (например: красный) может относится к нескольким товарам, я вижу такую структуру.

Таблица filters:

```
id|name |visible|
 1|цвет |true   |
```

Таблица filter_atributes:

```
id|filter_id|value    |
 1|        1|Красный  |
 2|        1|Синий    |
 3|        1|черный   |
```

Таблица product_filter_atributes:

```
id|filter_atribute_id|product_id  |
 1|                 1|4           |
 2|                 2|4           |
 3|                 1|12          |
```